# Numeric CAPTCHA validation in windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am creating a program that shows two random numbers on two separate labels then I have to add / subtract them and the answer should be entered in a textbox

How can I add or subtract the numbers and enter the answer on a textbox?

I am creating it in Visual Basic Windows Forms Application

Comment: @ pxtoxp : See my answer bellow for validating numeric captcha

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do some security technique. what ever it may i appreciate your try. based on the question and what am understand, i will give the following code as suggestion for you.

**Code to generate random numbers and random operators in label**

```
Dim op As Integer ' to represent the operator
Private Sub Generate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Generate.Click
    Dim Rand As New System.Random
    op = Rand.Next(0, 3)'randomly select operator 
    lblfirst.Text = Rand.Next(0, 10)'first random number
    lblsecond.Text = Rand.Next(0, 10)'second random number
    If op = 0 Then ' choosing operator based on op
        lblop.Text = "+"
    ElseIf op = 1 Then
        lblop.Text = "-"
    ElseIf op = 2 Then
        lblop.Text = "*"
    End If
End Sub
```

Following is the check button's click event that will evaluate the expression in label and check with the answer in the text box: display the message as result

```
 Private Sub check_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles check.Click
        Dim result As Double = 0.0
        If op = 0 Then
            result = CDbl(lblfirst.Text) + CDbl(lblsecond.Text)
        ElseIf op = 1 Then
            result = CDbl(lblfirst.Text) - CDbl(lblsecond.Text)
        ElseIf op = 2 Then
            result = CDbl(lblfirst.Text) * CDbl(lblsecond.Text)
        End If
        If result = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Correct")
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add two random numbers between 0-10:

```
        Dim Rand As New System.Random
        Dim Rand1 as integer = Rand.Next(0, 10)
        Dim Rand2 as integer = Rand.Next(0, 10)
        YourLabel1.Text = Rand1.toString()
        YourLabel2.Text = Rand2.toString()
        YourAnswerLabel.Text = Rand1 + Rand2
```

Comment: The Answer should be typed in a textbox

Comment: Then type the answer in to the textbox

Comment: Can you look at this website please :)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/c3ec3e64-e68d-42ba-9f34-6c9cb7c64cfa

I tried the codes that they were using but i get this warning message:

"A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"

can someone help me ????

Comment: @pxtoxp whilst you are learning i would ignore the first chance exception messages.  It just means that an exception was thrown and handled in some code you called before it returned control so it is of little consequence.